# i have added the scroll bar but it does not scroll up and down the frame

Tags: java, jframe, awt, jscrollbar

i have added the scroll bar but it does not scroll up and down the frame and i do not see the upper label i have created .
kindly give me any suggestion so i can scroll up and down in my frame.
i have a question also that when my frame size is fixed and i want to create 
many labels and text fields that i must have to scroll down so in that case i have to increase its frame size or not

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("jframe");
    JLabel[] labels=new JLabel[50];

  for (int i=0;i<labels.length;i++)
  {
        labels[i]=new JLabel("Column" + i);
  }


    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints cst = new GridBagConstraints();
    JScrollBar vbar=new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL, 30, 40, 0, 500);

    for(int i =0 ; i<50 ;i++)
    {    

         cst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
         cst.gridx = 0;
         cst.gridy = i;//
         cst.gridwidth = 2;
         panel.add(labels[i],cst);

    }       




    frame.getContentPane().add(vbar, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1300,700);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use a JScrollPane and put your panel on it?
take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("jframe");
    JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[50];

    for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
    {
        labels[i] = new JLabel("Column" + i);
    }

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints cst = new GridBagConstraints();
    //      JScrollBar vbar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL,30,40,0,500);

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {

        cst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        cst.gridx = 0;
        cst.gridy = i;//
        cst.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(labels[i],cst);

    }

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1300,700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: i run  the code given by you but it gives the following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 ScrollPaneConstants cannot be resolved to a variable

 at CreateProject.Window.main(Window.java:39)

Comment: it should be JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS